# store form data in an array using session

Tags: php, arrays, session

I want to add form data into an array using session.
How can I do this please help me.
My HTML form is:

```
    <form action="#" method="post">
    Roll No:<input type="text" name="rollno" value="" id="rollno"  />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

And my PHP code is:

```
    <?php
      session_start();
      $_SESSION['rollno'] = isset($_POST['rollno']);
      echo $_SESSION['rollno'];              
    ?>
```

I want to insert roll no into an array.

I have a record of 10 students. When I am inserting the first student Roll No then it prints the roll no, but when I insert the second student Roll No it overwrites the first student record.

I want to display all 10 student roll nos on same page.
How can I do this?

Comment: Then just append to the array.

Comment: Make the session var an array and use 'array_push' to add to it

Comment: I've never used `#` as the action such as `<form action="#" method="post">`.  Think it is a good idea?

Comment: @user1032531 it will point the form to itself

Comment: @Ander2.  Thanks.  Figured so.  Think it is a good idea?  Any security risks?

Comment: @user1032531 not for the `#` itself. But you should take care on that template for checking values, sanitizing variables, etc...

Answer (score 2):

1. Start the session before you out put any thing to the page, ie before html code
2. Make session a multi dimensional array
3. Remove `isset` from `isset($_POST['rollno']);`

   ```
   <?php
         session_start();
         $_SESSION['rollno'][] = $_POST['rollno'];
         print_r($_SESSION['rollno']);              
   ?>
   ```

Comment: how multi dimensional array will be created?

Comment: @AnjaniGupta.  PHP will automatically make it.  Probably more readable if you define it as one if it is currently not set.

Answer (score 1):

`$_SESSION['rollno']` should be an array not a simple variable.

Something like this:

```
  <?php
  //Define somewhere $_SESSION['rollno'] as array. ONLY ONCE. Note that session must be started.
  session_start();
  if (!isset($_SESSION['rollno'])){
      $_SESSION['rollno'] = array();
  }


  if(isset($_POST['rollno'])){
       array_push($_SESSION['rollno'],$_POST['rollno']);
  }
  foreach ($_SESSION['rollno'] as $item){
        echo $item;  
  }   
  ?>
```

Comment: Need session_start() before using sesssions.

Comment: I tried this but it print only last inserted value . I have to print all the 10 records.

Comment: @AnjaniGupta make sure $_SESSION['rollno'] is being defined only once. Otherwise you are creating the variable in every run, so it will only store the last value. I've edited the example.

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  if(isset($_POST['rollno'])){
      $_SESSION['rollno'] = $_POST['rollno'];
      echo $_SESSION['rollno'];        
  } 
}
```

Check first if form is submitted, then roll is set and if yes, assign it to session var.

Answer (score 0):

Almost there

```
<?php
  session_start();
  !isset($_SESSION['rollno']){$_SESSION['rollno']=array();}
  $_SESSION['rollno'][] = $_POST['rollno'];
?>
```

Also, recommend setting action to  something:

```
echo("<form action={$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']} method='post'>");
```

Some don't like to use PHP_SELF and recommend hard coding it

Answer (score 0):

i know !

Let's try :

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['rollno'] = Array();
$_SESSION['rollno'][] = $_POST['rollno']; 
$_SESSION['rollno'][] = $_POST['rollno'];
var_dump($_SESSION['rollno']);
?>
```

You can access it from loop too ..
Good luck